# Program defining if an input integer is divided by 2

Tags: mips

I am trying to make a program on QtSpim that constantly takes new integers as input (through the console) and then prints them on the console only when they are even numbers. I set the input 5 as the exit case. The program compiles as it should and when I press the run button there doesn't seem to have a problem. The problem is when I try to type the input number, as the console doesn't respond to that (the number I just typed doesn't even appear on the screen).
Here is my code, I imagine the mistake must be in the first lines where the input number is read, but I can't find it:

```
        .text
            .globl __start
    __start:
        li $v0,5
        syscall
        move $t0,$v0
        add $t1,$t0,$zero
        addi $t2,$zero,5
        LOOP:   div $t0,$t0,2
            bne $t0,$zero,LOOP
    mfhi $t3
    bne $t3,$zero,REPEAT
    li $v0,1
    move $a0,$t3
    syscall
    REPEAT:bne $t1,$t2,__start
    li $v0,10
    syscall

        .data
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with your code?

Comment: @user35443 the program is supposed to constantly read new integer input and decide if it is devided by 2. In that case the integer is printed on the console. It is also supposed to constantly read new input and repeat the procedure (print - if it is divided by 2,else - do nothing and just read the next input). The program stops when the input given is the number 5 (I chose it randomly, just so there isnt an infinιte loop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing can be done in a much simpler way, using the bitwise `and`.

Every odd number will have the last bit set, which will make `number & 1` equal to `1`.

```
.text
.globl __start
__start:
    li $t0, 5
    loop:
        move $v0, $t0       # set $v0 to 5: read integer
        syscall         # read in the number

        andi $t1, $v0, 1    # check if it's divisible by 2
        bnez $t1, check     # if no, jump to a check for 5

        move $a0, $v0       # if yes, print it
        li $v0, 1       # set $v0 to 1: print integer
        syscall         # do the printing
        j loop          # continue

        check:
            bne $t0, $v0, loop  # if the integer read is not equal to 5, run again

    li $v0, 10
    syscall             # exit
```

Comment: thank you very much, but when I run your code on QtSpim I cant enter an input number in the console which was my original problem..

Comment: @Konstantina the problem must be somewhere else. I tested this on MARS 4.5 and it worked perfectly

Comment: @Konstantina if my answer helped you, please, check the green "OK" button on the left to accept.

Answer (score 0):

Your method of checking for even numbers is incorrect. Whenever you enter a number >=1 you'll end up dividing 1 by 2 on the last iteration of your loop. And of course 1 MOD 2 is 1, so your code always thinks the number is odd.

A single division by 2 is sufficient to determine if the value is odd or even. But an `AND` operation would be even more efficient:

```
andi $t0,$t0,1   # if the least significant bit is set, the number is odd
bne $t0,$zero,REPEAT
```

After making that change you'll probably also have to change the printing code, since the value to print no longer is in `$t3`.